# Update value into SQLite db using C# or LINQ

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have model:

```
public partial class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Name { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class CityContext : DbContext
{
    public CityContext (DbContextOptions<CityContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<City> CityDBC { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasData(
             new City{ Id = 1, Name = "Rome"},
             new City{ Id = 2, Name = "Londyn"},
             new City{ Id = 3, Name = "Amsterdam"});

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Into controller I want to change `Name` for some `City`:

```
public IActionResult Change()
{
var selectedId = 1;
var newName = "Paris";

var checkCountCity = _cityContext.CityDBC.Count();// it's working, I got 3
var changeName = _cityContext.CityDBC.Where(x => x.Id == selectedId);

return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```

For DB I'm using **SQLite**.

How to **change** now **City Name** for **selected Id** ?

Comment: You want to update the value of name where id = 3 in your database?

Comment: yes, into my sqlite db

Comment: You can refer to the answer i updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this code to update record in linq.

```
 var cityToChange =  _cityContext.CityDBC.Where(x => x.Id == selectedId).FirstOrDefault();
 cityToChange.Name = "new name";
 _cityContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault() was missing on my site, thanks @Xinran

Comment: @4est JFYI you can move the filter delegate inside the `FirstOrDefault` (like in my answer) in this particular case skipping the explicit `Where`.

Comment: yes, got your suggestion

Comment: Everyday spotting issues with `FirstOrDefault` and not checking for `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you are using Entity Framework, so to [update the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/basic#updating-data) you need to fetch the entity to change, update it and save changes:

```cs
var cityToChange = _cityContext.CityDBC.Single(x => x.Id == selectedId);
cityToChange.Name = newName;
_cityContext.SaveChanges();
```

Also I would recommend to use async counterparts (`SingleAsync`, `SaveChangesAsync`, use `await` and change method declaration to `async Task<IActionResult>`) and possibly change `Single` to `SingleOrDefault` (or `FirstOrDefault` depended on the goal) and return not found if result is `null`.